# Show selected radio buttons in edit view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am having trouble displaying selected radio buttons in the `edit` action.

The app allows the `user` to create his own `forms`(surveys) and then apply them (answer them) to their `children`.

**The issue:**

When rendering the `new` action that allows the user to `answer` his form, `forms` display well, and save to database properly. Assigns the choices to the answer content.

On the other hand, `edit` action **duplicates** the choices, showing the ones that were selected AND new ones. I check the `id` of the answers and is rendering 2 times each answer.

**Any ideas of how to fix this behaviour?**

> Relevant code:

_form.html.erb

```
<%= f.fields_for :answers do |a| %>

  <% choices.each do |choice| %>

    <%= a.radio_button :a_content, choice.c_description %>
    <%= a.label :a_content, choice.c_description, :value => choice.c_description, class: 'no-margin' %>

  <% end %>

  <%= a.hidden_field :question_id, :value => question.id %>

<% end %>
```

answered_forms_controller.rb

```
  def new
    @child = current_user.children.find(params[:child_id])
    @form = current_user.forms.find(params[:form_id])
    @answered_form = @child.answered_forms.new(form_id: params[:form_id])
    @answered_form.answers.build
  end

  def create
    @answered_form = AnsweredForm.create(answered_form_params)
    if @answered_form.save
      flash[:success] = "Nuevo cuestionario " + @answered_form.form.f_title + " aplicado!"
      redirect_to current_user.children.find(params[:child_id])
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
    @child = current_user.children.find(params[:child_id])
    @form = current_user.forms.find(params[:form_id])
  end

  def update
    if @answered_form.update_attributes(answered_form_params)
      flash[:success] = "Cuestionario para paciente actualizado!"
      redirect_to @answered_form.child
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end
```

> UPDATE:

I now figured out that the duplication occurs because in the `new` action I got `@answered_form.answers.build`, but if I remove that, I don't see the fields when creating a new `answered_form`.

I knew this because tried to put 2 times `@answered_form.answers.build` in the `new` action and then got **duplicated** when creating and **triplicated** when editing, so `edit` always adds the fields one more time than `new` action if you have something like `@answered_form.answers.build` in the `new` action.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should be able to do something like:

```
<%= f.collection_radio_buttons :a_content, choice, :id, :c_description, {}, { checked: choices.selected_response_id }  %>
```

With this you should be able to generate your radio buttons for all your answers.

PS: the final hash has the condition for checking the selected option `choices.selected_response_id` you should change that to the selected response on your answer model.

Although Rails tries to infer the preselected radio button, it may not always work hence the reason for this final hash.

[Read more here](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_radio_buttons)

Comment: Could you elaborate more about `selected_response_id` method? I'm a little lost with that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to preselect your radio button, it means you have already stored a boolean value in your database for this field. Just insert this value after the checked option inside your helper:

radio_button_tag("something", something, checked = value)

should work the same with f.radio_button

Comment: Are you sure that it **has** to be a **boolean** value? I thought it has to be the same value, wether a string, integer, boolean, etc. Either way, your answer does not seem to work.

Comment: My mistake you are correct, this is not a boolean returned, but the second parameter in the radion_button_tag shown above. It's just I have stored a boolean value in my database. Lets say I have 4 radio button named Car, with different values being Ford, Fiat, Chrysler, Cadillac. I have not stored the brand of the car inside one field of my model, but I have instead 4 fields , each populated with True or False, for each possible car brand. This is a personnal choice. Though, whether you store the actual value in your database, or a boolean value. "cheched" can only be assigned a boolean value.

Comment: I've updated with progress, do you think you can help me with the new information that I've provided?

Comment: I am sorry, I just had a look but your code is pretty big and not really easy to read. (Thought it was only regarding the radion button helper). I may have a look at it later.